# Xpages - JS code fails to execute when clicked via a button

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a strange issue, where I have a simple javascript button, that call's 1 function to write some document history and replace the value of one field. It then does a partial update of a container div ID.

This button works fine when accessed via the UK, however when used by Swiss colleagues, the button is doing nothing.

I have in 1 instance, witnessed it not working for 1 user, only for it to suddenly work later in the day, so I'm stumped as to what the issue may be.

**Button Code**

```
<xp:button id="btnProceed" styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Proceed">
            
    <xp:this.disabled><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{
    if (getComponent("chkConfirmed").getValue() == "false") {
        return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }
 }catch(e){
openLogBean.addError(e,this);
}
}]]></xp:this.disabled>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="contentWhiteBackground">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dt = new Date();
var arrHistory:array = AddIndepConfirmationHistoryItem(currentDocument, dt, "Confirmed understanding of the opening guidance", userBean.displayName);
document1.replaceItemValue("showIntroduction", "2");
document1.save();
}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

**Called code**

```
Sub AddIndepConfirmationHistoryItem(confdoc As NotesDocument, dt As Variant, action As String, usrname As String)
    Dim hlist As StringList
    
    If Len(confdoc.History(0)) = 0 Then
        confdoc.History = IndepConfirmationHistoryItem(dt, action, usrname)
    Else
        Set hlist = New StringList(confdoc.History, "")
        Call hlist.Append(IndepConfirmationHistoryItem(dt, action, usrname))
        confdoc.History = hlist.Items
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

```
function AddIndepConfirmationHistoryItem(doc, dt, action, username){

var ArrDocHistory:array = doc.getItemValueArray("History");

var dateTimeFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm");
var dateTimeString = dateTimeFormat.format(dt);


    if(ArrDocHistory.length < 1){
        // This should always return an object as it is created when an objectives document is first 
        // created but do this check to be safe and create an array if for some reason it doesnt exist
        ArrDocHistory = [dateTimeString+"|"+action+"|"+username];
    }else{
        // append new value to the array
        ArrDocHistory.push(dateTimeString+"|"+action+"|"+username);
    }
    doc.replaceItemValue("History",ArrDocHistory);
    doc.replaceItemValue("LastUpdatedByName",username);
    doc.replaceItemValue("LastUpdatedDate",dt); 
    //doc.Save();
}
```

Comment: If Len(confdoc.History(0)) = 0 Then. --> change in === or == and try again.

Comment: That looks like LotusScript... So "=" would be right. But I have never seen that you could call LotusScript like this - are you sure that is the function you're callling?? And not an SSJS function with the same name? Add some print statements to see how far you get in the code.... (print('xxxx') in SSJS)

Comment: Whoops, yes, the SSJS version is of the function is in the edited question, I'll get some print statements in aswell.

Comment: Ah, not my best first comment... Anyway, did you check F12 to see if there is some network activity when the button is clicked in Switzerland? Also check if a js Date is a Java Date. IMHO there's no need to pass it as a parameter anyway.

Comment: Yes, F12 shows nothing happening at all. There is a checkbox that when clicked changes the button from state disabled to not, which works, but clicking does nothing. I'm waiting to here back from them, its hard to troubleshoot as there are differences in IT architecture between UK and CH that I can't replicate to test easily.

Comment: Tracked it down to two 404 errors, fontawesome-webfont.woff and fontawesome-webfont.ttf. My extension lib version is 9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214 which is the highest I can currently goto unless upgrading to FP9. Any idea why the 404 errors are only coming when accessed from Switzerland?!

Comment: Actually, trying to access the files directly is also giving me a 404 error [SERVER]//xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/responsive/dijit/dbootstrap-0.1.1/theme/dbootstrap/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf